# Crashlytics with StrictMode enabled (detect all) gives "untagged socket detected"

Tags: android, crashlytics-android, android-strictmode

I've tried adding `Crashlytics` to my app, which already has `StrictMode` enabled with `detectAll()`. The result was `Untagged socket detected; use TrafficStats.setThreadSocketTag() to track all network usage`.

Full Stack:

```
E/StrictMode: null
java.lang.Throwable: Untagged socket detected; use TrafficStats.setThreadSocketTag() to track all network usage
    at android.os.StrictMode.onUntaggedSocket(StrictMode.java:2012)
    at com.android.server.NetworkManagementSocketTagger.tag(NetworkManagementSocketTagger.java:78)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.tagSocket(BlockGuardOs.java:47)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.socket(BlockGuardOs.java:310)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:667)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketCreate(PlainSocketImpl.java:116)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.create(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:98)
    at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Socket.java:484)
    at java.net.Socket.getImpl(Socket.java:547)
    at java.net.Socket.setSoTimeout(Socket.java:1175)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:139)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:112)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:407)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:538)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source:0)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.code(HttpRequest.java:1357)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsSpiCall.handleResponse(DefaultSettingsSpiCall.java:104)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsSpiCall.invoke(DefaultSettingsSpiCall.java:88)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsController.loadSettingsData(DefaultSettingsController.java:88)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsController.loadSettingsData(DefaultSettingsController.java:65)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.Settings.loadSettingsData(Settings.java:153)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.retrieveSettingsData(Onboarding.java:126)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.doInBackground(Onboarding.java:99)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.doInBackground(Onboarding.java:45)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.doInBackground(InitializationTask.java:63)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.doInBackground(InitializationTask.java:28)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:311)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
W/System.err: StrictMode VmPolicy violation with POLICY_DEATH; shutting down.
```

I tried to create a new project and it was the same, the code in `MainActivity` in the test project:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    setCrashlytics();
    setStrictMode();
}

private void setCrashlytics() {
    Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
}

private void setStrictMode() {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .detectAll()
                .penaltyLog()
                .build());
        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
                .detectAll()
                .penaltyLog()
                .penaltyDeath()
                .build());
    }
}
```

I did see that [Okhttp has this issue](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3537) (as well as other libs) but I do not know if that is relevant.
I'll add a workaround as an answer (basically don't use `detectAll()`), but I wonder if there is a proper solution for this, maybe there's a way to add the tag to the socket?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A workaround is to not use `detectAll()`, I've copied the the code of `detectAll()` (from Crashlytics) and modified it; however I had to remove part of code since there are classes that are inaccessible.
I'm not a huge fan of this workaround but I'm not sure there's a better solution.

```
private void setStrictMode() {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .detectAll()   // detectDiskReads, detectDiskWrites, detectNetwork
                .penaltyLog()
                .build());

        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(getStrictModeBuilder().build());
    }
}

private StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder getStrictModeBuilder() {
    StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();

    builder.detectLeakedSqlLiteObjects();

    final int sdkInt = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (sdkInt >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        builder.detectActivityLeaks();
        builder.detectLeakedClosableObjects();
    }

    if (sdkInt >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        builder.detectLeakedRegistrationObjects();
    }

    if (sdkInt >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        builder.detectFileUriExposure();
    }

    if (sdkInt >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        builder.detectContentUriWithoutPermission();
    }

    builder.penaltyLog().penaltyDeath();
    return builder;
}
```

**Option two** - remove the `penaltyDeath()` from the `VmPolicy` - this is what I'm currently doing:

```
private void setStrictMode() {
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .detectAll()   // detectDiskReads, detectDiskWrites, detectNetwork
            .penaltyLog()
            .build());

    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
                .detectAll()
                .penaltyLog()
                .build());
}
```

Comment: Can this be written in Kotlin?

Comment: Someone also suggested this workaround in the github issue: `TrafficStats.setThreadStatsTag(10000);` -- basically just set the tag to a random number before any sockets are created. But honestly, either this should be excluded from detectAll or all these libs should just fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Api 28 has introduced:

```
public StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder penaltyListener (Executor executor,
                StrictMode.OnVmViolationListener listener)
```

So at least you can listen for specific violations (like UntaggedSocketViolation) and choose to ignore them. Of course, it would be better if Crashlytics were to tag their sockets appropriately.

Comment: How do we ignore them?