# StrictMode: How to disable "Untagged socket detected" in Android for targetSdk >= 28

Tags: android, android-strictmode

I'm trying to disable one of Android StrictMode checks - detection of untagged sockets.

I have several reasons to do this:

- Some libraries used in our app e.g. Crashlytics / Picasso e.t.c.
  are using OkHttp internally and StrictMode detects untagged socket 
  problem in OkHttp code (I don't have access to code of third party libraries to fix this problem there)
- I need to clear my logs from strict mode untagged socket errors which I can't fix to remove noise for other StrictMode problem detection

To enable VmPolicy We use [VmPolicy.Builder.detectAll()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder#detectAll()) method

By looking in sources of StrictMode I've found method VmPolicy.Builder.permitUntaggedSockets but it annotated as `@hidden` and can't be used on API = 28

The only [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53195069/2285038) to this problem I've found is to copy `detectAll()` method body to my code and remove call to `detectUntaggedSockets()` but it seems to me error prone and weakly maintainable.

May be some one can suggest better solution to described problem?

Any information about "Why `permitUntaggedSockets()` became hidden in API 28" are really appreciated.

[Crashlytics: Details about StrictMode problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53195068/crashlytics-with-strictmode-enabled-detect-all-gives-untagged-socket-detected)

[OkHttp: Bug report about Untagged socket problem](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3537)

Answer (score 7):

so for your question was:

> Any information about "Why permitUntaggedSockets() became hidden in
>   API 28" are really appreciated.

My answer is ( that is a good question ! XD) 
I think that the StictMode needs at least a good JavaDoc we are not asking too much.

The good news for you is that there is a solution for this problem which is based on a new the 28-API and here is my code snippet:
https://gist.github.com/houssemzaier/cf69f9a614f9550408872349e5798e0b

Have a good day!