# Firebase Strictmode resource leak

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, resource-leak

After converting from Crashlytics via Fabric to Crashlytics via Firebase, I started seeing the below call stack in debug runs where StrictMode is enabled looking for resource leaks.

StrictMode is in use with this code, only on debug builds:

```
StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
    .detectLeakedClosableObjects()
    .penaltyLog()
    .build());
```

I'm using this versions of Fabric's gradle tools in project-level gradle:

```
classpath "io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.27.0"
```

and these versions of Firebase and Crashlytics in module-level gradle:

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7"
implementation "com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.8"
```

During initialization, the Firebase instrumentation kicks off a background thread that is doing settings calls using okhttp. When it does, StrictMode causes this call stack to pop:

```
W/CrashlyticsCore: Received null settings, skipping report submission!
D/StrictMode: StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.LeakedClosableViolation: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidCloseGuardReporter.report(StrictMode.java:1786)
        at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.warnIfOpen(CloseGuard.java:264)
        at java.util.zip.Inflater.finalize(Inflater.java:398)
        at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:250)
        at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:237)
        at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:103)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'end' not called
        at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:221)
        at java.util.zip.Inflater.<init>(Inflater.java:114)
        at com.android.okhttp.okio.GzipSource.<init>(GzipSource.java:62)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.unzip(HttpEngine.java:473)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:648)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:471)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:407)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:538)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:26)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.code(HttpRequest.java:1357)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsSpiCall.handleResponse(DefaultSettingsSpiCall.java:104)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsSpiCall.invoke(DefaultSettingsSpiCall.java:88)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsController.loadSettingsData(DefaultSettingsController.java:90)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsController.loadSettingsData(DefaultSettingsController.java:67)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.Settings.loadSettingsData(Settings.java:153)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.retrieveSettingsData(Onboarding.java:126)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.doInBackground(Onboarding.java:99)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.doInBackground(Onboarding.java:45)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.doInBackground(InitializationTask.java:63)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.doInBackground(InitializationTask.java:28)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:311)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
D/FA: Event not sent since app measurement is disabled
```

I see this happening on pretty much every debug run of my app, during the initial activity startup in the app. However support claims they don't see this.

Does anyone know what conditions cause Fabric to kick off this onboarding/settings thread?

I've seen similar StrictMode call stacks in these other posts. I can't tell if this leak is in Fabric code, or in the okhttp library they are using.  Here are links to similar cases where people are seeing what looks to me like the same underlying resource leak:

[StrictMode penalising for Firebase Ads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51919951/strictmode-penalising-for-firebase-ads)

[Crashlytics with StrictMode enabled (detect all) gives "untagged socket detected"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53195068/crashlytics-with-strictmode-enabled-detect-all-gives-untagged-socket-detected)

https://github.com/cloudant/sync-android/issues/577

Comment: If you think there is a problem inside a Firebase SDK, you should file a bug report.  http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features

Comment: already tried that, they claimed they can't reproduce. Want me to send a repo that reproduces the problem, but have declined multiple times to tell me what conditions are required for Firebase to start this thread with the issue. Without that info I'd have to experiment a repo until I can get a reliable reproduction of the issue. I'm hoping someone is willing to share that info so I don't have to waste time experimenting